# Hiding spaces with zero values in bar chart with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've got bar charts with multiple labels and zero data values for some labels.

[image]

I need to hide zero-values in chart and draw bars in the middle of current label value. How can i do it?

Here source code:

```js
var chartDebugData = {
    labels: ["2021-11-16", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-18"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Data1",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(161, 198, 76, 0.5)",
            borderColor: "rgba(161, 198, 76)",
            data: [
                66,
                77,
                0,
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
        },
        {
            label: "Data2",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(107, 228, 46, 0.5)",
            borderColor: "rgba(107, 228, 46)",
            data: [
                55,
                0,
                82,
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
        },
    ]
}

const canvasEl = document.getElementById("charts");

// Draw graph
new Chart(canvasEl, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartDebugData,
    options: {
        barValueSpacing: 5,
    },
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/70n3h1r4/4/

Answer (score 3):

Solution was simple: replace zero values with `null` and add option `skipNull: true,`

Here struct with data:

```js
var chartDebugData = {
    labels: ["2021-11-16", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-18"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Data1",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(161, 198, 76, 0.5)",
            borderColor: "rgba(161, 198, 76)",
            data: [
                66,
                77,
                null,
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
            skipNull: true,
        },
        {
            label: "Data2",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(107, 228, 46, 0.5)",
            borderColor: "rgba(107, 228, 46)",
            data: [
                55,
                null,
                82,
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
            skipNull: true,
        },
    ]
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tLzhm6p9/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom plugin to go into the propertys before the draw, check if its the only bar if so make it wider and replace it on the chart:

```js
var chartDebugData = {
  labels: ["2021-11-16", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-18"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "Data1",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(161, 198, 76, 0.5)",
      borderColor: "rgba(161, 198, 76)",
      data: [
        66,
        77,
        0,
        0
      ],
      borderWidth: 2,
    },
    {
      label: "Data2",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(107, 228, 46, 0.5)",
      borderColor: "rgba(107, 228, 46)",
      data: [
        55,
        0,
        82,
        0
      ],
      borderWidth: 2,
    },
  ]
}

const canvasEl = document.getElementById("charts");

// Draw graph
new Chart(canvasEl, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: chartDebugData,
  options: {
    barValueSpacing: 5,
  },
  plugins: [{
    beforeDatasetsDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
      const zeroPositions = chart.data.datasets.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        curr.data.forEach((dp, i) => {
          if (dp === 0) {
            acc[i] ? acc[i]++ : acc[i] = 1
          }
        });
        return acc;
      }, {});

      chart.data.datasets.forEach((d, di) => {
        const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(di);

        d.data.forEach((dp, i) => {
          if (zeroPositions[i] !== chart.data.datasets.length - 1 || dp === 0) {
            return;
          }
          if (i === 0 && meta.data[i].width !== meta.data[i + 1].width) {
            return;
          } else if (meta.data[i].width !== meta.data[i - 1].width) {
            return;
          }

          meta.data[i].width = meta.data[i].width * chart.data.datasets.length;
          meta.data[i].x = chart.scales.x._labelItems[i].translation[0];
        });
      });
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="charts" width="900" height="450"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support! Answer was to much easy, than i thought. You can see it in other answer for this issue.

Comment: Aah yeah totally forgot about that property