# ChartJS - Mixed Chart: Bars and Line

Tags: chart.js

I have a bar chart with a single line on it. The information is displayed correctly, but each bar "dataset" is reserving space for the other bars when they will never appear in that Y position.
I have attached an image and a jsfiddle with the relevant information. https://jsfiddle.net/bXXzW5/x97tnLu1/

`Is there a way to not have each X label reserving space for other bars?`

[image: image of chart]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding spaces with zero values in bar chart with chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70245106/hiding-spaces-with-zero-values-in-bar-chart-with-chart-js)

Comment: that looks like the correct answer, but when i added it to the json data it had no effect. perhaps it is not supported with the x, y data format and needs to be used with an array... i will need some time to be able to reformat my data and try again